# Python Selenium: How to click on see-more buttons in a loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to scrap the website https://www.wlw.de/de/suche?employeeCounts=200%2B_50-199&q=blechbearbeitung&supplierTypes=Dienstleister_Hersteller with multiple repetitive divs elements that each has a see-more button to show the hidden data in the div
I tried to find buttons using Selenium in Python with this code

```
for i in range(len(company_names)):
    seemore_button = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'toggle-button')[i]
    seemore_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Where company_names is the name of each div and I am using its length to loop on all divs but it doesn't work, when I run this code the chrome driver acts as clicking on buttons but when it finishes I find that not all the buttons have been clicked
I thought at first that it may be because of the page can't load as fast as the code clicks the buttons so I added a sleep time of 2 seconds and the same result, sometimes the buttons are clicked and sometimes no

Comment: Would be great if you could provide some more details (HTML/URL/ Is there always a button to click,...) to clarify. Based on your information it is not possible, to investigate what exactly went wrong. Thanks

Comment: @HedgeHog Done, I added the website to the question

Answer (score -1):

To click on all the ***show more*** links in a loop you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.wlw.de/de/suche?employeeCounts=200%2B_50-199&q=blechbearbeitung&supplierTypes=Dienstleister_Hersteller')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#CybotCookiebotDialogFooterButtonAcceptAll>button"))).click()
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.toggle-button span")))
  for elem in elements:
      elem.click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.wlw.de/de/suche?employeeCounts=200%2B_50-199&q=blechbearbeitung&supplierTypes=Dienstleister_Hersteller')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='CybotCookiebotDialogFooterButtonAcceptAll']/button"))).click()
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='toggle-button']//span")))
  for elem in elements:
      elem.click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Dear @undetectedSelenium can you look at my question? your vast knowledge can solve my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74528243/using-javascript-in-selenium-command-is-revoked-by-windows-security-settings) better