# Using JavaScript in Selenium command is revoked by Windows security settings

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating a web page with selenium-python where there's a `hidden JavaScript` button. The HTML is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> add_itemtitle("Restart"); </script><div class="content_item_title">Restart</div>
<div class="maintenance_item">
<div class="maintenance_item_desc">
Click <b>Restart</b> to restart device
</div>
<div class="maintenance_item_butt">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
create_button("Restart","btnReboot");
</script><span class="button_wrapper" id="btnReboot"><span class="button_left"><span class="button_right"><span class="button_center">Restart</span></span></span></span>
</div>
</div>
```

I have been using following codes but it didn't worked for me.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnReboot"]'))).click()
```

and `execute_script`

```
"""working with javascript buttton """
#1
#element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()[contains(.,'Restart')]]")))    
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
#2
#element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Restart']"))).click()
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
#3
#submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()[contains(.,'submitButton')]]")))    
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit_button)
```

leads to `Virus&theart protection`
[image: Virus&theart protection]

> Controlled folder access blocked
> chromedriver.exe from making changes.ckick to
> see setting.

is there any selenium option like following to evade the `Virus&theart protection`

```
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#disable security content
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
```

Comment: chromedriver injects a dll. This is likely what's causing the warning. You probably need to whitelist `chromedriver.exe`.

Comment: The thing that's complaining is "Windows Security", a part of Windows. I would suggest searching "windows 10 security whitelist"

Comment: You don't avoid it. The injection is required in order for Selenium to work.

Comment: can it be solved by using options like options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'), I am not admin in my computer

Comment: No. It has to do with Windows security settings. If you're not an administrator on that computer, you won't be able to use Selenium on that computer.

Comment: @Ouroborus I appreciate your time and dedication for solving my issues.

Comment: @RF1991 I saw this your question when you asked it, but unfortunately I don't know how to help here. It's not something I ever faced with. I'm sorry :(

Comment: Maybe Debanjan will be able to help.  https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/undetected-selenium